# problem when giving a pointer in parametres of a function, with the mainCRTStartup

Tags: c, pointers, crt

i have to precise that i am a total beginner in programming, and my english is not very good as well, and i am using codeBlocks;
so the problem is when passing a pointer in parametres of a the 'initQueue()' function like the first call (in the code) it works jeut fine, but when i try the second one (which i have to do for my project), it crashes. when i run it in debug mode and onpen the call stack it shows me that there is a problem in , but when i try the third one it works agian (which is not what is supposed to happen , i guess)

```
typedef struct process{
    char id[10];
    int size;
}PROCESS;

typedef struct cel{
    PROCESS proc;
    struct cel *next;
}CELLE;

typedef struct queue{
    CELLE *head;
    CELLE *tail;
}QUEUE_;

void initQueue(QUEUE_ *f){
    f->head = NULL;
    f->tail = NULL;
}

// In the main function
// First call
QUEUE_ q;
initQueue(&q);

// Second call
QUEUE_ *q;
initQueue(q);

// Third call
QUEUE_ *q;
initQueue(&q);
```

Comment: Your second pointer points to nothing. Dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Unless you've got different scoping, compiling your code produces errors. That fact that `q` is defined three times in the same scope is flagged as an error. That aside, the second call should be: `QUEUE_ *q = malloc(sizeof(QUEUE_)); initQueue(q);` The third should be fixed similarly except that you want `initQueue(q);` You're mixing up `QUEUE_` variables and _pointers_ to `QUEUE_` variables. Within the same scope, would you want to use _different_ names (e.g.) `q`, `q2`, and `q3`?

Comment: First thanks for answering, Actually, I didn't put them in the same scope, i just wanted to show different things that I've tried

Comment: 1st call is fine. 2nd call needs the `malloc` fix. And, 3rd call would need `malloc`, but it needs to be like 2nd call (i.e. `initQueue(&q)` --> initQueue(q)`) because it's a pointer. Thus, 3rd call [corrected] is just a duplicate of #2. In the 3rd call [as you have originally], doing `&q` is passing a `QUEUE_ **` pointer and not `QUEUE_ *` as you'd want.